# Enter username and password in login form on a webpage

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

Using Excel VBA, I'm trying to login to a website.

This is my code:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Website_Login()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

sURL = "https://www.domain.com/login.html"

Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
'oBrowser.Silent = True
'oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
Loop Until oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

With HTMLDoc
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("username").Value = "user"
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("password").Value = "password"
End With

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
  oHTML_Element.Click
  Exit For
Next

oBrowser.Quit

End Sub
```

The Javascript instructions in this code are working. If I go to the page and enter them, they work. But when I run the code, IE opens but it doesn't enter the user/pass and click the button.

Any help, please?

Comment: I need to see the actual url

Comment: check the browser is not busy also, but that looks ok.Set ele2 = doc.getElementById("search_terms")
ele2.Value = "TEST VAL" is what I've used in the past

Comment: without seeing the URL - replace `.getElementById("username").Value = "user"` with `.getElementByName("username").Item(0).Value = "user"` (and same for password). Also use IE developer tools to find the name of the button to click and place `If Instr(1, oHTML_Element.Name, "ButtoName") Then` in front of  `oHTML_Element.Click`. Otherwise, you may click another button unintentionally.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks, but I still can't enter user/pass in the form. BTW you may see the HTML following the link on my comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this code and it worked.

The only difference is that I used `Late Binding` (too lazy to set all references) and I added `While .Busy` to the Loop to wait for the URL to load. I also changed `input` to `button` in the button click loop.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As Object 'HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As Object 'InternetExplorer

Sub Website_Login()

Dim oHTML_Element As Object 'IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

sURL = "https://www.mypage.com/login.html"
Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'New InternetExplorer
'oBrowser.Silent = True
'oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

With oBrowser
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: Loop
End With


Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

With HTMLDoc
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("username").Value = "user"
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("password").Value = "password"
End With

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
  If oHTML_Element.Name = "Submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click
  Exit For
Next

oBrowser.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Whoa, it's also working here! Would you please change the sURL in your code so that I won't have the world trying to login to the website? :-) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Edited it out. I also changed 'input' to 'button'. Forgot to add that first time. Please mark as answered if it is indeed so.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the 'input' had to be changed to 'button', but it happens the page has more than one button, so it isn't clicking on the right one yet.

Comment: See my edit. Added an `If` statement to test button name. However, I only saw one button on the page when I tested it.